# Setting img src attribute in javascript without loading the resource

Tags: javascript

In my javascript I have this line below that changes the src attribute in a img tag to `'cid:logoImage'`. When the javascript is executed, I receive an error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`. Is there a way to set the src to this attribute without actually trying to load or check the validity of URL in javascript?

```
document.querySelector(".emailTemplateSubmit #newsletterLogo").src = 'cid:logoImage';
```

Answer (score 1):

src attribute without triggering validity check, you can use the setAttribute method instead of directly setting the src property.

```
document.querySelector(".emailTemplateSubmit #newsletterLogo").setAttribute('src', 'cid:logoImage');
```

Comment: I just tested this code, still getting the exact same error.

Comment: cid:logoImage URL scheme is not recognized by the browser.. You can test it with a base64 image. 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...'

Comment: I know it is not recognized. This line of html code is intended to be used in a html email. This code will be submitted to backend, where a image will be attached in a email and sent. Is there a way to ignore this error or tell browser not to do URL validation?

Comment: One way to do this is to encode the image data as a base64 string and include it directly in the HTML code using a data URI, as I explained in my previous response. (I recommend this method.) Another option is to host the image on a server and use a URL in the HTML code.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using the base64 string. The problem is that many email clients such as Google cannot interpret base64 string and show it as an image. I will accomplish this task from backend modifying the src tag from backend.